# how to update locally cloned git repo with changes from the original project (no fork!)

Tags: git

I am a bit new to git so I may misuse git terminology in the following...
Searching for a an answer I only found cases, where a fork (that is: another repo on github or similiar) was created - which I don't want (yet). Or it least: This is the way I think I understood it....

What I want is:
To clone a github repo of a project located on github onto my harddisk (already done).
Makeing changes to that cloned repo and don't put those online (because they are highly experimental
in this moment).
And I want to be able to update my cloned repo with changes made to the mother/father original repo on github without overwriting my changes (by risking conflicts from time to time...).

Is this possible and how can I accomplish this?

Comment: you can just do `git pull` (assuming you are on master) if there are conflicts it will let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no significant difference if you use a fork (different [remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote.html)) or the original repository ([origin](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjDgszu6fXsAhVklMMKHbuOCsEQFjABegQIBhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.git-tower.com%2Flearn%2Fgit%2Fglossary%2Forigin%2F%23%3A%7E%3Atext%3DIn%2520Git%252C%2520%2522origin%2522%2520is%2Cbut%2520just%2520a%2520standard%2520convention.&usg=AOvVaw3HA5pxG-qEEU5pHFrYmCkm)) while synchronizing the remote changes to your local branch. What you are trying to achieve is a common git workflow routine and you can get it either by [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#_description) command or [`git pull --rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#_description). The final outcome will be the same from your perspective - you will keep your local changes (commits) and you will be up-to-date with the remote changes at the same time. However, the history log can be slightly different. See [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/when-do-you-use-git-rebase-instead-of-git-merge) if you want to dive into the details.

Comment: You should either `git commit` before you call `git pull` or, if you don't want to commit your changes yet, you can do a `git stash` before `git pull` then `git stash pop`.

Comment: Ah! Enlightenment! :) Thanks a lot!